# Deserialize HTTP response - getting null value

Tags: c#, http

I would like to deserialize the below HTTP response to a class using Newtonsoft JsonConvert. However I am getting null value when I try to deserialize. I used to json2csharp to generate a class but for this "@odata.etag" field it gives me a field called `public string __invalid_name__@odata.etag { get; set; }` which may not be correct.

Can I remove this field from the payload as I dont need it? Also , can someone help me how I can remove this field. Alternatively can I can de-serialize the existing payload with the correct fields in the class?

```
 - Payload(response contains an array of 5000, below is a sample of one)

    {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"201865260\"",
            "new_ispioneer": false,
            "new_emailconfirmed": true,
            "merged": false,
            "msdynhcp_unsubscribeurl": null,
            "emailaddress1": "xxx@xxx.net",
            "new_emailverificationlastsent": null,
            "new_alphaplayer": false,
            "isbackofficecustomer": false,
            "_owningbusinessunit_value": "d80d1db5-c580-e611-80e3-c4346bac697c",
            "_owninguser_value": "157924d5-f69c-e611-80e6-c4346bac6938",
            "lastname": "xxx@xxx.net",
            "donotpostalmail": false,
            "marketingonly": false,
            "donotphone": false,
            "preferredcontactmethodcode": 1
        }
```

Below are my classes

```
public class contact
{
    public string __invalid_name__@odata.etag { get; set; }
    public bool new_ispioneer { get; set; }
    public bool new_emailconfirmed { get; set; }
    public bool merged { get; set; }
    public object msdynhcp_unsubscribeurl { get; set; }
    public string emailaddress1 { get; set; }
    public object new_emailverificationlastsent { get; set; }
    public bool new_alphaplayer { get; set; }
    public bool isbackofficecustomer { get; set; }
    public string _owningbusinessunit_value { get; set; }
    public string _owninguser_value { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public bool donotpostalmail { get; set; }
    public bool marketingonly { get; set; }
    public bool donotphone { get; set; }
    public int preferredcontactmethodcode { get; set; }
}

public class ContactList
    {
        [JsonProperty("Contact")]

        public IList<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using code to try to deserialize where

```
if (createResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) //200  
                {
                    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(createResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                    var Raw = obj.SelectToken("value");
                    var collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ContactList>>(Raw.ToString());
}
```

Collection contains a list of objects each of which is null.

Comment: Have you tried to use a `JToken` instead of a `JObject` ? Also check that last comma `,` after `"preferredcontactmethodcode": 1` should not exist.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't exist.Error in the post here, corrected

Comment: You're deserializing an object with properties (your json file) into a c# class with a list property, there's no array or whatnot in your json file, try deserializing it either with `.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(...)` or with `.DeserializeObject<List<contact>>(...)`.

Comment: To handle json properties that don't have a legal C# identifier name, or even to just make your C# class nicer naming-wise, use the `[JsonProperty("@odata.etag")`] attribute on your C# property, then you can name your C# property whatever you find most fitting.

Comment: FYI: Use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute : `[JsonProperty("someCrazy_value"]`, it will make your properties a lot cleaner

Comment: When I used jsonutils.com, I got `[JsonProperty("@odata.etag")] public string OdataEtag { get; set; }` for your property. I believe this should resolve your deserialization problems.

Comment: Appreciate all your help people! Using the attribute enabled me to achieve what I wanted to do. Many thanks!!